# How are levels for Super Mario Maker 2 licensed?

Tags: legal, super-mario-maker-2

Who owns copyright on the Super Mario Maker 2 levels produced by users?  My initial assumption had been Nintendo, but I have been unable to find the EULA available publicly.  Do level creators have any right to use alternative distribution networks outside of the official Nintendo ones?  Or, for that matter, to acquire levels from such distribution networks?  What about using 3rd party level design tools?  It would also help to know if there's somewhere I can access the EULA without needing to make an account...

Answer (score 7):

**Update**

As my understanding, if you use SuperMarioMaker2 to create a course *but didn't publish it*, you should still have right on your course.

But I am not a lawyer, my understanding could be wrong...

---

I didn't find the EULA either. However, I remember what Nintendo says at game beginning :

---

**(translate from Chinese by my own)**

Nintendo may take those course you created and published, directly use, or refine it, and sell them as part of future Nintendo games. Once Nintendo takes your course, we(Nintendo) will not pay anything to you, and you're not able to claim any reward.

---

So, I don't really care about if Nintendo takes my courses, I still enjoy on create/play/share courses to everyone.  :-)

Comment: Seems like the logical conclusion to remaking the same game over and over: "Screw it, we'll have the players make it and we'll sell it back to them". Brilliant.

Comment: I don't think Nintendo will do things like that... Actually, most UGC platform have similar user agreement that user can not claim right on those content they generated and published to this platform. Nintendo is no exception.

Comment: @RRTW I agree, I guess it's more to prevent them from having trouble if they publish some new games with parts of some courses that may look like courses already created by users.